# Possible to use UNION to join 3 result queries together, yet keeping the columns distinct?

Tags: sql, oracle, union

So here's my question (i'm using Oracle SQL by the way)

I have 3 result queries from my database (one is total number of hotels, one is number of hotels being constructed and one is number of hotels completed).

How do you join all three queries, so that i get 1 row, and 3 distinct columns? I've tried using `UNION`, but all that gets me is 1 column, but 3 rows.

My code looks like this:

```
 (SELECT COUNT(Hotel.hotelName) AS TotalHotels FROM Hotel)
 UNION
 (SELECT COUNT(Hotel.hotelName) AS NumConstructing FROM Hotel
 WHERE NOT EXISTS
 (SELECT Room.* FROM Room WHERE Room.hotelNo = Hotel.hotelNo))
 UNION
 (SELECT COUNT(Hotel.hotelName) AS NumCompleted FROM Hotel
 WHERE EXISTS
 (SELECT Room.* FROM Room WHERE Room.hotelNo = Hotel.hotelNo));
```

And the resulting output looks like this:

```
TOTALHOTELS
-----------
  2
  8
 10
```

I need it so that there's only one row, and 3 columns.

Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The general answer, which also works when your `SELECT` results have more than one column, is:

```
SELECT TotalHotels, NumConstructing, NumCompleted
FROM
    (SELECT COUNT(Hotel.hotelName) AS TotalHotels FROM Hotel)
    AS TotalHotels
CROSS JOIN 
    (SELECT COUNT(Hotel.hotelName) AS NumConstructing FROM Hotel
     WHERE NOT EXISTS
     (SELECT Room.* FROM Room WHERE Room.hotelNo = Hotel.hotelNo))
    AS NumConstructing
CROSS JOIN
    (SELECT COUNT(Hotel.hotelName) AS NumCompleted FROM Hotel
     WHERE EXISTS
     (SELECT Room.* FROM Room WHERE Room.hotelNo = Hotel.hotelNo))
    AS NumCompleted;
```

although in this case, you don't need the union/cross join:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(1) AS TotalHotels,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN NOT EXISTS
     (SELECT 1 FROM Room WHERE Room.hotelNo = Hotel.hotelNo) THEN 1 END) AS NumConstructing,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN EXISTS
     (SELECT 1 FROM Room WHERE Room.hotelNo = Hotel.hotelNo) THEN 1 END) AS NumCompleted
FROM
    Hotel;
```

Answer (score 1):

In the really basic conversion:

```
select 
(SELECT COUNT(Hotel.hotelName) FROM Hotel) AS TotalHotels 
, (SELECT COUNT(Hotel.hotelName) FROM Hotel
   WHERE NOT EXISTS
   (SELECT Room.* FROM Room WHERE Room.hotelNo = Hotel.hotelNo)) AS NumConstructing 
, (SELECT COUNT(Hotel.hotelName) FROM Hotel
   WHERE EXISTS
   (SELECT Room.* FROM Room WHERE Room.hotelNo = Hotel.hotelNo)) AS NumCompleted
from dual;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
 (SELECT COUNT(Hotel.hotelName) FROM Hotel) AS TotalHotels,
 (SELECT COUNT(Hotel.hotelName) FROM Hotel WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT Room.* FROM Room WHERE Room.hotelNo = Hotel.hotelNo)) AS NumConstructing,
 (SELECT COUNT(Hotel.hotelName) FROM Hotel WHERE EXISTS (SELECT Room.* FROM Room WHERE Room.hotelNo = Hotel.hotelNo)) AS NumCompleted
```

Comment: You can't have a query without a `FROM` clause in Oracle.

Comment: em..sorry, Oracle is not my native language.

Answer (score 0):

It's done by using subqueries and dual table:

```
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(Hotel.hotelName) FROM Hotel) AS TotalHotels,
       (SELECT COUNT(Hotel.hotelName) 
          FROM Hotel
         WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT Room.* 
                             FROM Room 
                            WHERE Room.hotelNo = Hotel.hotelNo)) AS NumConstructing,
       (SELECT COUNT(Hotel.hotelName) AS NumCompleted  
          FROM Hotel
         WHERE EXISTS (SELECT Room.* 
                         FROM Room 
                        WHERE Room.hotelNo = Hotel.hotelNo))
  FROM dual;
```

However for performance I'd use something like this (sorry for possible typos):

```
SELECT Count(DISTINCT h.hotelNo) TotalHotels,
       Sum(Decode(r.hotelNo,
                  NULL, 1,
                  0) NumConstructing,
       Sum(Decode(r.hotelNo,
                  NULL, 0,
                  1) NumCompleted
  FROM Hotel h,
       Room  r
 WHERE h.hotelNo = r.hotelNo (+)
```